# What is my SQL query for my condition?

Tags: mysql, select

i have two table related by mutual ID..
i want to display all the name in table A, but with some extra information that,
is the name in table A exist in table B or not?
this is the example

Table A

```
+-----------+------+
| Mutual ID | Name |
+-----------+------+   
|     1     | A    |   
|     1     | B    |
|     1     | C    |
|     1     | D    |
|     1     | E    |
+-----------+------+
```

Table B

```
+-----------+------+
| Mutual ID | Name |
+-----------+------+   
|     1     | A    |   
|     1     | B    |
|     1     | C    |
+-----------+------+
```

i want an output like this

```
+------+---------+
| Name |hasMutual|
+------+---------+   
| A    |   Yes   |   
| B    |   Yes   |
| C    |   Yes   |
| D    |   No    |
| E    |   No    |
+------+---------+
```

please help me with the query.. Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for left-joining `TableB` to `TableA`. If there isn't a corresponding `TableB` row, its values will be `NULL`.

This should give you your desired output:

```
SELECT
  TableA.Name,
  CASE WHEN TableB.Name IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS hasMutual
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name
WHERE TableA.MutualID = 1
ORDER BY TableA.Name
```

Comment: thanks Ed for your answer.. it's give me some clue for creating my output